# Program to lint YAML files?

Tags: yaml, lint

So my team is currently working on an application that uses a lot of YAML and we need to enforce some rules for common formatting. The best would be a command-line program so we can plug it into our CI.

Most importantly, we want to force 2-space indentation and indentation of lists, like this:

```
list:
- not indented
- not indented            # this is BAD

list:
  - indented
  - indented              # this is GOOD

mapping:
     5 space indentation  # this is BAD
```

Also it would be great to preventing trailing spaces and non-sense syntaxes.

I've found some websites that check YAML validity (i.e. whether it's possible to load it or not) -- but no linting. The same for yaml-lint, a Ruby app that only "checks if your YAML files can be loaded".

**Is there a linter for YAML**, similar to flake8 for python or eslint for javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [yamllint](http://yamllint.readthedocs.org/). In your CI:

```
sudo pip install yamllint
yamllint file1.yml ...
```

It's highly configurable. Specifically, for 2-space indents and forcing list
indentation, the conf would be:

```
rules:
  indentation: {spaces: 2, indent-sequences: yes}
```

(It also handles trailing spaces, line-length etc.)

Have fun!